# Suprising integral inequality with the Gamma function : $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\pi-e-\left(x\right)!}dx<3$

Tags: inequality, improper-integrals

I really want to share this integral inequality with you so let me propose it:

### $$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\pi-e-\left(x\right)!}dx<\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(x^{-x}+e^{-x}\right)dx<3$$

For first information the integral is around $2.99511$ wich is pretty close to $3$

For second information without the constant $\pi$ and $e$ the integral diverges .

We have a pretty good linear approximation wich states :

Let $x\in(0,1]$ then we have :

$$f'\left(1\right)\left(x-1\right)+f\left(1\right)\leq f(x)$$

Where :

$$f\left(x\right)=x^{x!}$$

We can also play with the function $g(x)=x^{x}$ adding some coefficient .

Side notes :

We can show something stronger using the speed light https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light

How to show it analytically ?

Comment: How is this related to speed of light?

Comment: I believe that the integral $\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha-x!}dx$ converges for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Nice I suggest you to make an answer if you can finish.^^

Comment: Try graphing $x^{-\gamma}$ with the euler mascheroni constant to get an approximation on $(0,1)$

Comment: Please, explain the speed of light reference! Furthermore, as Easymode mentions, the necessity of using $\pi-e$ as a constant is extremely dubious: please elaborate on what you meant by that.

Comment: @Fshrike It's just a funny intuition .For the constant it's for the beauty but we can also use rational numbers .